# Checking whether the current thread equals the thread on which an object was constructed

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check within `someObj.someMethod()` if it is being executed on the same thread on which `someObj` was created? This could save me a debugging headache later on if I mess up certain concurrency constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do that is to store the thread-id when you create it. On .NET 4.5:

```
readonly int ownerThreadId;
public SomeType() {
    ownerThreadId = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
}
```

then check against that same term in `someMethod`.

Note that on other framework versions, you might need:

```
ownerThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

instead.